# What's a word for the contents of a book are different and more helpful than the cover depicts

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

The book's cover is "People Can't Drive You Crazy If You Don't Give Them The Keys" but the content of the book is more about changing yourself and your perceptions and attitude and more. TOC snapshot, Part 1:  Stuck in a Crazy World, Part 2: Changing Someone Else, Part 3: Changing Yourself, Part 4: Changing Your Environment, Part 5: Putting It Into Practice.

BTW... Really good book.

Answer (score 1):

How about an adverb or leading adverbial phrase like “unexpectedly”? Or “surprizingly”? “This little volume with its  goofy name and cutsy chapter headings was surprizingly rich in content. “Unexpectedly, given its title, this book was a valuable and insightful addition to the ranks of the self help publications...”.

Comment: You mean *surprisingly* and *cutesy*.